Create table (in R) with Average,Sd,CI (descriptive analysis) for age and Weight and Absolute,relative frequencies,Cumulative frequencies for gender
How can I create a table that I can present continuous variables such as age and weight with descriptive analysis? (mean, standard deviation, 95% Confidence interval for the mean. I also want to present categorical variables in one table with absolute, relative, and cumulative frequencies.
I have added a new variable based on other variables and it runs but when I am trying to use that new variable it gives me the error "variable not found".
I am starting to learning how to create tables to present statistics. Which packages can I use and how do I do it for continuous variables or categorical variables?

For future reference including your code is always good when asking a question. It gives a better idea of what you're actually trying to accomplish. There are a ton of different packages that produce summary statistics. In the base R environment, you can call
summary(your.data.frame)
and it gives some basic info.
When you start to go a little deeper everyone is going to have their own preferences, I actually really like the psych package for summary statistics when dealing with continuous variables.
If you aren't familiar and are still learning. This package can be installed and loaded using:
install.packages("psych")
library(psych)

From here, you can use 'describe(your.data.frame)' and index the columns with the statistics you want to store for a new data frame. For example:
new.df <- describe(your.data.frame)[,c(2,4,7,9)]

These are the columns you want to pull from.
I'm not familiar with a package that also includes a T-test for variable CI's in an all in one stop. However, the base R package has a nice function that can perform a t-test to produce CI's for a vector.
t.test(your.data.frame$your.variable, conf.level = 0.95)$conf.int

This is going to perform a t-test on a given variable. You could write a small function to store results in a new dataframe and use cbind() to combine it with your summary statistics.
For your question about summary stats for categorical variables, you can index those out of your original data frame and use some different methods to create the results you want. I will keep updating this, but for now check out these links, they provide a more comprehensive explanation.
https://bookdown.org/rwnahhas/IntroToR/summarizing-categorical-data.html
https://uc-r.github.io/descriptives_categorical
